# WPF MediaElement opacity does not fade in gradually after changing source

Tags: wpf, vb.net, storyboard

I have a WPF digital signage application that displays a slideshow of images and/or videos. I'm using a single MediaElement object and the transition is handled by storyboard animations of the Opacity property.

The image always fades out smoothly, but the fade in doesn't. The Opacity appears to stay at 0 for the length of the animation duration, and then go to 1 in one go.

```
Private Function GetFadeInStory() As Storyboard
    Dim story As New Storyboard
    Dim fadeInAnimation As New DoubleAnimation With {
        .BeginTime = New TimeSpan(0),
        .From = 0,
        .To = 1,
        .Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(My.Settings.FadeInDuration)}
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, New PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty))

    story.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation)
    Return story
End Function

Private Function GetFadeOutStory() As Storyboard
    Dim story As New Storyboard
    Dim fadeOutAnimation As New DoubleAnimation With {
        .BeginTime = New TimeSpan(0),
        .To = 0,
        .From = 1,
        .Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(My.Settings.FadeOutDuration)}
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOutAnimation, New PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty))

    story.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation)
    Return story
End Function

Private Sub DisplaySlideImage()
    Dim slideUri As Uri = GetNextSlidePath()
    Dim s As Storyboard = GetFadeOutStory()
    AddHandler s.Completed, Sub() FinishedFadeOut(slideUri)
    Storyboard.SetTarget(s, mediaElement)
    s.Begin()
End Sub

Private Sub FinishedFadeOut(slideUri As Uri)
    mediaElement.Source = slideUri

    Dim s As Storyboard = GetFadeInStory()
    Storyboard.SetTarget(s, mediaElement)
    s.Begin()
End Sub
```

However, if the MediaElement.source property does not change, the fade in and fade out work as expected. I've tried without success:

- Wrapping the mediaelement.source change in BeginInit / EndInit statements
- Calling mediaelement.UpateLayout after changing the source
- Recreating the mediaelement object with every slide

Any ideas?

Comment: For the time being, I've replaced the MediaElement object with an Image object. The rest of the code stayed pretty much the same, other than using a BitmapImage object as a source. The Opacity fade in and fade out now works as expected, but of course I've lost the ability to show video.